# Kaspersky slows down the clients. How do i find the real cause?

Tags: windows, performance, anti-virus

At my work, we have 15 client pc's with Windows 7. As it turned out. Kaspersky slows down each pc. The Problem started couple days ago. And for example, when i click on Computer -> properties -> change settings . It takes 20 seconds to pop-up the window. When i shut down the Anti-Virus it takes, less than 2 seconds.

I don't think, that shutting down the anti-virus protection is the best solution.
So : **What can i do about it ?**

Comment: I found the problem. There is a bug in the 2011 (400 build )
I deinstalled it and installed Kaspersky Internet Security 2012.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the issue only started a coule of days ago, what else may have changed? Any updates?

Some AV apps have a setting to scan all files wherever accessed and this slows things down.  There is also a setting to scan only when changed or created that avoids scanning each and every file every time you do something.  If you have done a full scan and then set to scan only on creation or change, you should be protected and performance should improve.